# BigQuery Help - How to cast and convert to float and date format

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I'm trying to do two things in BigQuery, but I'm having difficulties doing so.

I'd like to do two things :

1. Convert my date columns to Date format (it is currently in `int64`, with `43379` as an example)
2. Cast my columns `Delivered_Cost` and `Actual_Cost` to `float` (they are currently with string type) - As when there is a null value, there is `-` instead of `0`. When you cast to `float`, do these `-`s automatically change to `0` or do I have to update that first?

I don't have much experience this, and I've been having difficulties looking for a solution online so I'd love any help! I'm having difficulties casting and displaying data from my table at the same time.

Thank you!

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE1
CAST(Delivered_Cost as float)
```

Comment: I guess you are using Standard and not Legacy queries, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1. Convert my date columns to Date format (it is currently in int64, with 43379 as an example)

Use [function `PARSE_DATE()`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/date_functions#parse_date) :

```
PARSE_DATE(Delivered_Date, '%Y-%m-%d')
```

The [following doc](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators#supported-format-elements-for-date) lists the supported formats.

> 2. Cast my columns 'Delivered_Cost' and 'Actual_Cost' to float (it is currently with string type)

Your syntax with `CASE()` is OK ; you could also use shortcut method `FLOAT()`. However if your string does not successfully maps to a float (like `-` alone), a runtime error will occur. You could use [`SAFE_CAST()`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators#safe-casting) to ignore conversion error, but that might also lead to ignoring relevant errors. Hence, you would better use `REPLACE()`.

Here is your query :

```
SELECT
    PARSE_DATE(Delivered_Date, '%Y-%m-%d') AS Delivered_Date,
    FLOAT(REPLACE(Delivered_Cost, '-', '0')) AS Delivered_Cost,
    FLOAT(REPLACE(Actual_Cost, '-', '0')) AS Actual_Cost  
FROM MYTABLE


FLOAT(Delivered_Cost)
```

Comment: Thank you! When I use the code below, it somewhat works:

SELECT
  --PARSE_DATE(START_DATE, '%y-%m-%d') AS START_DATE,
  float(replace(delivered_cost, '-', '0')) AS Delivered_cost
 FROM table

However, the '-' values get changed to null rather than 0s. Also when I try to do multiple REPLACE functions in the same query, I get an error. Please see the below code for an example:

SELECT
  --PARSE_DATE(START_DATE, '%y-%m-%d') AS START_DATE,
  float(replace(delivered_cost, '-', '0')) AS Delivered_cost
  float(replace(total_planned_units, '-', '0')) AS total_planned_units
FROM table

Comment: Apologies - I'm also new on stackoverflow so I'm unfamiliar with how to paste the code in a friendly way.

Comment: so if it doesn't works for you I guess you shouldn't accept the answer in order to no drive other users to wrong conclusions. Did it finally worked?

Answer (score 1):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```sql
#standardSQL
SELECT 
  DATE_FROM_UNIX_DATE(date_column_as_number_of_days_since_epoch) date_since_epoch,
  IFNULL(SAFE_CAST(Delivered_Cost AS FLOAT64), 0.0) AS Delivered_Cost,
  IFNULL(SAFE_CAST(Actual_Cost AS FLOAT64), 0.0) AS Actual_Cost
FROM `project.dataset.table`
```

You can test, play with it using dummy data as below

```sql
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT 
    43397 AS date_column_as_number_of_days_since_epoch,  
    '123' AS Delivered_Cost,
    ' - ' AS Actual_Cost 
)
SELECT 
  DATE_FROM_UNIX_DATE(date_column_as_number_of_days_since_epoch) date_since_epoch,
  IFNULL(SAFE_CAST(Delivered_Cost AS FLOAT64), 0.0) AS Delivered_Cost,
  IFNULL(SAFE_CAST(Actual_Cost AS FLOAT64), 0.0) AS Actual_Cost
FROM `project.dataset.table`
```

with result as

```sql
Row date_since_epoch    Delivered_Cost  Actual_Cost  
1   2088-10-25          123.0           0.0
```

Note: I am assuming that `43379` which you use as an example in your question is actually a number of days since epoch - as this is most reasonable from my point assumption - let us know if this is something else, so I will adjust answer respectively